# CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected on Walther MFS100 Check Scanner

Tags: c#

i am trying to programming an interface for Walther Mfs100 Check scanner but after the scan i get "CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected" error. How can i fix this. I use .net 2.0 with c#

```
[DllImport("mflib.dll.stdcall")]
        public static extern int mfScanFeeder(int mode, int font, int timeout);

 retval = modMFS100.mfScanFeeder(0, 2,5000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't this particular API call that's the source of the problem.  The API is too obscure and too poorly documented to give a straight answer, but look for an initialization style function that let's you set a callback.  That callback is the cause of the exception.  You must create a delegate object and store it in a field of your class.  That way the garbage collector sees a reference to it and won't garbage collect it.

Thus, instead of:

```
void SetupScanner() {
    mfInitialize(something, myCallback);
}
```

Do it like this:

```
SomeDelegateType callback;

void SetupScanner() {
    callback = new SomeDelegateType(myCallback);
    mfInitialize(something, callback);
}
```

Contact the vendor for support if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some info about this error: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/665b876d-9070-41de-9a3a-d2093895d0c2

You can try to use static variable for your delegate, this will prevent the delegate from being garbage collected.

Comment: You, sir, are awesome! @rotman deserves a medal! static did it for me for the same problem.